# Make button readonly after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, forms

So I have a form with multiple buttons each which have a Request mapping in a controller.

So I want to stop double submission of the form, but I can't disable the button after clicking as the controller can't get the information it needs to knwo what to do.
This is the error I get:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "update" OR "verify" OR "reject" OR "updateCard" OR "approve" OR "withdraw" OR "updateStatusToReject" OR "updateStatusToApprove" not met for actual request parameters:
```

So I feel making the button readonly after clicking would fix this issue.

I have tried this so far, but it still allows the double submission.

```
 $('.sendButton').click(function(){
        $(this).prop('readonly', true);
    });



<c:if test="${requestForm.status == 'R'}">
                <input type="submit" name="updateStatusToApprove" value="Update To Approved" tabindex="7"
                       class="sendButton" id="appealA"/>

            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${requestForm.status == 'A' || requestForm.status == 'AA'}">
                <input type="submit" name="updateStatusToReject" value="Update To Rejected" tabindex="8"
                       class="sendButton" id="appealR"/>
```

Any ideas how to stop the double submission without actually disabling the button.

Comment: I think read-only means you are disabling button, and you can also do this by restricting the submission of your call untill your previous request won't get fulfilled first.

Comment: Or you can keep the input type as button instead of submit and assign a handler that executes only once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your **input** of **type** `button` and assign a `click` handler that execute only once using [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```js
$('.sendButton').one( "click", function(){
    //submit the form
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="updateStatusToReject" value="Update To Rejected" tabindex="8" class="sendButton" id="appealR"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however changing the input to a button gave me the same error as listed above. However I took your solution and just kept it as an input and styled it as a button. Now it works thanks.